# NGRX effect only getting final omission from combineLatest

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I return a `combineLatest` from my service thats a collection of requests to my backend. I listen to it in my effect via `switchMap`. The requests work as intended and then when they all complete I get my response in my effect.

What I need however is to listen to the emissions as they happen. I've also tried using `zip` but no luck. The only emission I get is the final one.

The code is something like this:

```js
// Effect
createEffect(() => {
   return this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(someAction),
      switchMap(action => { 
        return this.service.doSomething().pipe(
           tap(results => ...nothing happens until the end),
           map(results => ...do stuff)
        )
      })
    )
});

// Service

public doSomething() {
   const requests = someData.map(data => this.http.get(...))

   return combineLatest(requests).pipe(
      tap(results => // nothing happens here until the end
   )
}
```

Any ideas? It seems like under the hood NGRX is discarding other emissions

Answer (score 0):

NGRX doesn't discard emissions.
From the question it seems like you're looking for the `merge` operator instead of `combineLatest`. `merge` will emit each value that is returned.